# ImportError: No module named inception

Tags: tensorflow

Im using imagenet train script (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/imagenet_train.py) to train my own image data set to classify in tensorflow (in Oracle VM Virtual box) and im getting an error as below

shri@shri-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Test/inception_test/models/inception/inception$ python imagenet_train.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imagenet_train.py", line 25, in 
    from inception import inception_train
ImportError: No module named inception

Could someone please help understand the problem and how do i fix it?

Regards,
Shri

Comment: Did you download all the files in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception/inception or just the one you linked?

Comment: i downloaded all the files from github

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a [Python module search path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) issue. The `import` statements in the particular script [`imagenet_train.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/bc70271a51fe2e051b5d06edc6b9fd94880761d5/inception/inception/imagenet_train.py) and other scripts in that directory assume that they can find the other scripts in a submodule called `inception`, but when you run the script from the same directory, Python can't find that submodule.

The easiest way to fix this is to change to the parent directory (`cd ~/Desktop/Test/inception_test/models/inception`) and run the script as follows:

```
$ python inception/inception_train.py
```

Comment: still facing a problem

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inception/inception_train.py", line 30, in <module>
    from inception import image_processing
ImportError: No module named inception